# Has "⿰面了" been suggested as a analogical simplification of 䩍?

Tags: simplified-characters

I was looking at: 䩍. I figured there might have been an analogical simplification suggested that looked something like: "⿰面了". [Zisea](http://zisea.com/zscontent.asp?uni=4A4D) doesn't offer any variant characters. [Baidu](https://www.baidu.com/s?wd=%22%E2%BF%B0%E9%9D%A2%E4%BA%86%22&rsv_spt=1&rsv_iqid=0xf720d96d0000937d&issp=1&f=8&rsv_bp=0&rsv_idx=2&ie=utf-8&rqlang=&tn=baiduhome_pg&ch=) offers zero results for a search of "⿰面了". [Google](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk02nhzuYiyXIwLpguXN_5e7h04CLQg%3A1587471442899&source=hp&ei=UuSeXuiiNIqg6ASc46Ag&q=%22%E2%BF%B0%E9%9D%A2%E4%BA%86%22&oq=%22%E2%BF%B0%E9%9D%A2%E4%BA%86%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQA1BJWElghwNoAHAAeACAAZgBiAGYAZIBAzAuMZgBAKABAqABAaoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjok8X7v_noAhUKEJoKHZwxCAQQ4dUDCAY&uact=5) gives two results for "⿰面了" but they're both false-positives.

I realize that 䩍 is not a very *important*(?) character. It was only added into Unicode in [CJK Ext. A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs_Extension_A). But, it is not entirely uncommon for a CJK Ext. character to have an analogical simplification (e.g.: , CJK. C; , CJK. G).

Has "⿰面了" been suggested as a analogical simplification of 䩍? Perhaps it needs to have been published for it to gain any traction first, though.

Comment: I think there's been a not-so-correct idea floating around that PRC Simplified everything. Actually that's not true, PRC standardises slightly over 8000 characters, and anything out of that number it decided to standardise is not subject to any kind of usage/regulations and therefore not "simplified".

Comment: @dROOOze I don't think it's PRC, necessarily doing all the simplification. I think it's more likely to be individuals and scholars. I have found undigitized analogical simplifications before in published works and passed them along to IRG groups for standardization.

Comment: I tried 國學大師's 部件 search (http://www.guoxuedashi.com/zidian/bujian/) and 小學堂's 古今字資料庫 (http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/ccdb), can't find a character with both 面 and 了 regardless of position. MoE variants don't record any variation on the character (https://dict.variants.moe.edu.tw/variants/rbt/word_attribute.rbt?quote_code=QzE1NzYx). I guess the next thing to do is to search for topolectical words which have survived, cognate to 䩍, see if they have any variant representations.

Well, good luck :)

Comment: Didn't make it onto the [1981 second-round simplification](http://glyphwiki.org/wiki/Group:%E7%AC%AC%E4%BA%8C%E6%AC%A1%E6%B1%89%E5%AD%97%E7%AE%80%E5%8C%96%E6%96%B9%E6%A1%88%E3%83%BB%E4%BF%AE%E8%AE%A2%E8%8D%89%E6%A1%88), unlike 嘹/僚/寮/燎/潦/镣

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but actually no.

Yes, because the 2.9.008 rule of the second part of the Second Stage simplifications (1977-1978) postulated simplifying 尞 to 了 **wherever** it occurs: 撩, 瞭, 缭, etc.

No, because all the simplification schemes are explicitly referring to popularly used characters only, and the practice was and remains to avoid overindulging in simplifications: texts where such characters can occur are probably about the character itself, and thus its original form is preferred. 䩍 (U+4A4D) is not even remotely a popular character, with its only claim of fame being the appearance in the Kāngxī Dictionary.

By the way, note that in the actual Second Stage, were it implemented, 面 is simplified into  (U+2BA51) as well (rule 1.2.009). So, ⿰了 is the actual IDS you are looking for, looking like this (http://glyphwiki.org/wiki/u2ff0-u2ba51-u4e86, just drew it):

[image: 䩍]

Comment: What a hideous-looking character.

Comment: People have already edited it at http://glyphwiki.org/wiki/u2ff0-u2ba51-u4e86 , now it looks nicer.

Comment: I don't think anyone can do anything to make that little guy look any better.